# Remove white spots from depth image with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm processing depth image from Kinect sensor using OpenCV with Emgu wrapper for motion detection using background substraction technic. On frames from Kinect I've noticed places with white spots, which I would like to filter off, make them in color of background. Which OpenCV technic/function should be used for this purpose?

White places are presented on pic:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[inpaint](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) will do that,

For this,

- Create a mask corresponding to the region to be filled, use [Threshold Binary Inverted](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#threshold-binary-inverted) with high  value to create mask.
- Now apply `inpaint`, on source with above mask, adjust `inpaintRadius` till you get better result.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use erosion filter after thresold .